# Halide: Var declaration format

Tags: halide

When declaring a Var inside a Halite generator class, why does one need to use curly braces like

```
Var x{"x"}
```

if it is outside the function of generate(), while if it is inside the function of generate(), one can use either curly braces or parentheses like this

```
void generate()
{
    Var x("x");
    Var y{"y"};
}
```

What are the differences of these two methods of declaration and why is the required format different for inside and outside of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that is how C++ syntax works. Curly braces are called "uniform initialization" and are a new feature in C++11. Parentheses are constructor syntax from basically the first version of C++ and are only allowed in certain places. Halide is embedded in C++ and thus can neither eliminate the standard constructor syntax nor add it to places where it is not supported. Search for "C++ uniform initialization" to get more information.